# Java hook only for one specific orientDB database

Tags: orientdb

I have been able to create a java hook exactly with the method specified here:
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Tutorial-Java-Hooks.html

But I don't want my hook to run for every database present on the server. I want to enable it only for one specific database.

Is it possible to do that simply by specifying it declaratively on the orientdb-server-config.xml ? or By configuring the hook in my Java class extending `ODocumentHookAbstract` ? Otherwise any idea how to do it programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this programatically by conditionally registering your hook based on the database name and implementing the database life cycle listener `ODatabaseLifecycleListener`. From the docs on [hook self registration](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Java-Hooks.html#self-registration), you can do this in the overridden `onOpen()` method with something like:

```
public class MyHook extends ODocumentHookAbstract implements ODatabaseLifecycleListener {

 ...

  @Override
  public void onOpen(final ODatabase iDatabase) {
    if("someSpecificDatabaseName".equals(iDatabase.getName()) {
      // REGISTER THE HOOK
      ((ODatabaseComplex<?>)iDatabase).registerHook(this);
    }
  }
}
```

[ODatabase.getName() javadoc](https://orientdb.com/javadoc/2.2.x/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/ODatabase.html#getName--)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing finally. Obviously there isn't a built-in construct or configuration to bind a database to the hook.